# How to generate Entity Relationship (ER) Diagram of a on-premises database using Azure Data Studio (macOS)?

Tags: sql-server, erd, azure-data-studio

I found a [similar question for SQL Server Management Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32379038/how-to-generate-entity-relationship-er-diagram-of-a-database-using-microsoft-s). But I use latest Azure Data Studio on macOS. We use on-premises SQL Server (not Azure cloud).

How can I use Azure Data Studio to generate an ERD from an existing database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Azure Data Studio doesn't have database diagramming built in.

This means you're asking a shopping question, and here's [how and where to ask a shopping question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199411/where-can-i-ask-a-question-about-finding-general-software-that-meets-certain-req).

Comment: https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2019/06/11/sql-server-management-studio-ssms-18-1-is-now-generally-available/ 
They came back. Which means this is no longer a shopping question.

Comment: It came back to SSMS, not Azure Data Studio. The feature isn't in ADS, so Ivanov will be shopping.

Answer (score 2):

Actually Azure Data Studio has plenty of extensions that do this.  There's a plugin called Schema Visualization that will do it.  I'm sure there are others.  Also SQL Management Studio offers an [ERD export tool that's built-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32379038/how-to-generate-entity-relationship-er-diagram-of-a-database-using-microsoft-s).  If you're on-prem you should be able to connect it.